# How to Design your SQL database in Azure?

Tags: azure, model-view-controller

I am following the example in ch13 of *Pro ASP.NET MVC5* about deployment website to Azure.
My problem is I can't see any `Design your SQL database` Links after I click my dateBase. Any ideas?
I tried both IE and chrome. Do I need to install something to make the popup appear?

[image]

Update: There's no manage links below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]When you click on your database You'll see Connect to your database section , choose `Design your SQL Database` there

Or just click on the `Manage` link located further down in the screenshot you provided

Comment: I can't see it.But I guess it's because I used the local Azure service from China.

Comment: I'm currently using different subscription (company account) but 6 months ago I used free trial (30 days) and was reading the same book and had no issues -  as soon as I log in to management portal and then in the databases section select the database I created I was presented with a screenshot similar to the one I've shared...